# Changing content in Angular UI Bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to have a counter in my Bootstrap UI modal, but I'm having some difficulty doing so. The code looks something like this:

```
var openSessionWarningModal = function () {
    var markup = '<div class="modal-header"><h3 class="modal-title ng-binding">Are you still working?</h3></div>';
    markup += '<div class="modal-body"><p class="ng-scope">Please confirm you are still working or your session will be ended in <b>{{$ctrl.secondsRemaining}}</b>.</p></div>';
    markup += '<div class="modal-footer"><button ng-click="$ctrl.ok()" class="btn btn-primary ng-binding" type="button">Yes, I\'m still here</button></div>';
    this.close();
    $modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        backdrop: 'static',
        template: markup,
        windowClass: 'modal-session-timeout',
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        controller: ['$scope', 'modalManager', function ($scope, modalManager) {
            var $ctrl = this;
            $ctrl.ok = function () {
                modalManager.close();
            };
            $ctrl.secondsRemaining = 60;

            var timer = setInterval(function () {
                $ctrl.secondsRemaining--;
            }, 1000);
        }]
    });
};
```

I'm able to see the initial value of 60 in the UI, but as the timer decrements `$ctrl.secondsRemaining`, it does not update in the UI.

Comment: use `$interval` instead of `setInterval`

Comment: @PankajParkar the problem is not with the timer. it's updating the UI...

Comment: $interval invokes a digest. setInterval does not. @PankajParkar is correct

Comment: @PankajParkar I see!  You were right.  Thanks!